# TFS (2012) security 'deny' permission denies everyone even admins granted 'allow'

Tags: tfs

From what I can tell, if you ever use 'deny' to anything, it overrides EVERYTHING and denys access.  For example, you have a 'contributors' group and you want to 'deny' them 'Manage Branch' to keep people from making branches.

Sounds good, but as an Admin, I happen to also be in that group, and even though I have set 'project collection administrators' group to 'allow' the 'deny' overrides it!

I'd like to change this behavior to grant access if any of my permissions grants it (like about every other security model I've worked with)  as it is, it looks like I need to be sure that none of the admins are in ANY other groups - or we will be locked out of those!

This makes the 'deny' almost useless - only good for creating a 'former employees' group or something where you want them locked out of everything and want to be able to turn that on.

Oh, I'm using TFS 2012

Answer (score 6):

That's correct. The `Deny` permission trumps all other permissions.

Think of it like this:

- `Allow` means something is explicitly allowed.
- `Not Set` means that something is denied unless it's overridden by an `Allow`.
- `Deny` means that something is denied **even if** it's `Allow`ed elsewhere.

It's worth noting that this is exactly the same as how Windows security works.

Comment: So getting added to a group can totally REMOVE your admin rights.   Windows does it the same broken way?  I'm pretty sure that isn't right.  If I'm a Domain Admin, but also a member of the Printer Users group, I should still be able to do other things with the printer than what the print users group can.  That would make windows 'deny' permission worthless, AND dangerous! However, in TFS, is there a way to setup a project that Admin's can change everything but all 'contributors' can't? - even if that Admin is a contributor?  (similar to how windows works)

Comment: I can't for the life of me imagine a situation where 'deny' would be a good or useful thing with this implementation.  (other than the former employees situation.)

Comment: It's not at all broken. You're explicitly saying "People who are part of Group X shouldn't be able to take Action Y." When you have someone who is both explicitly Allowed and explicitly Denied, something has to take precedence. Deny takes precedence. If you want to Deny people who aren't Allowed, you don't set any explicit permission for them.

Comment: But yes, Windows file permissions work in exactly the same way: http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs-permissions-precedence.htm

Comment: Actually, no:  from that page: "An explicit "allow" permission can take precedence over an inherited "deny" permission."  This is not true in TFS, where an inherited Deny trumps everything.  I was trying to figure out if there was any way to avoid that, or configure something to change the behavior.  It appears that I can't.